# jQuery: How to specify element in this case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a function that adds game results to a schedule.
I want to have the score of a winning team in yellow - add `".winner"` class to (`<%=score1%>` or `<%=score2%>`).
I wonder what is the correct way to specify needed element, using jQuery.
My current code isn't working. All elements get `".winner"` class, regardless of whether a team won or not.

```
addGame: function(gameInfo) {
    var sHtml = window.JST["schedule/gamelist/inner_row"](gameInfo);
    var tableRow = $("<tr>").append(sHtml);
    tableRow.data("id", gameInfo.id);
    return tableRow;
}

addNewTable: function(date, gameInfos, number) {
           ...
           ...
    for (var ind = 0; ind < gameInfos.length; ++ind) {
        gameInfo = gameInfos[ind].attributes;
        var element = this.addGame(gameInfo);
        $("#schedule_mytable_tbody" + number).append(element);

    if (gameInfo.score1 > gameInfo.score2)
        $("li:nth-child(5)").find("p:first-child").addClass("winner");
    else
        $("li:nth-child(5)").find("p:last-child").addClass("winner");
    }
```

My template looks like this.

```
window.JST["schedule/gamelist/inner_row"] = _.template(
    '<td width="668px">\
        <ul>\
            <li class="schedule_..."></li>\
            <li class="schedule_..."></li>\
            <li class="schedule_...."></li>\
            <li class="schedule_..."></li>\
            <li class="schedule_boxscore">\
                <p><%=score1%></p>\
                <p><%=score2%></p>\
            </li>\
                            ...
```

Rendered HTML part:

```
<li style="font-size:16px" class="schedule_boxscore">
   <p class="winner">2</p>
   <p class="winner">10</p>             
</li>
```

So, because of the "for" loop, all paragraphs get the `".winner"` class, not just `<p class="winner">10</p>`...

Comment: Can you add an additional info (e.g. a `class='<%=winnerOrLoser%>'` to the paragraph) so you can point it directly with JQ?

Comment: use diff class name, add more class

Comment: @patel.milanb I updated question details.

Comment: need your rendered HTML than your code... please put HTML in your question

Comment: what's the `typeof` of gameInfo.score1?

Comment: @patel.milanb I added part of rendered html.